# Installing Ubuntu with secure boot on and no way to disable it?

Tags: boot, uefi, unetbootin, secure-boot

I don't have any OS installed. I wanted to install Win10 but it failed with error code 0x80070570 during install.

Now, I want to go back to Ubuntu but I am not able to (Only Unetbootin screen shows with a 'Default' option, and no way to move forward). When I boot the computer I am not able to go to BIOS or Boot options even if under Dell logo it says F2 for Setup and F12 for boot options. I think Win10 enabled secure boot or fast boot (?!).

I am stuck! I can't go to UEFI firmware settings and I cannot boot Ubuntu USB stick.
What can I do?

Is there a command that I can use in order to access UEFI firware settings next time I boot (I have a Win10 setup USB)?

Comment: How did you create the USB stick? If you did it from Windows, try doing it using `rufus`, because Unetbootin has many problems with the new versions of Ubuntu, UEFI and Secure Boot.

Comment: I did it from Mac OS with Unetbootin. I don't have any Windows machines. Only one with Mac OS

Comment: Ok, then I don't know how to help you. Let's wait for someone more expert than me on Mac OS :)

Comment: Secure boot or fast boot should be available on BIOS/UEFI. Remove all USB drives from laptop, shut it down and wait for 1-2 minutes ( to let the RAM memory settle clear). Restart laptop and you should be able to access BIOS. If that still doesn't happen, you need to reset the BIOS by temporary removing the BIOS battery on the mainboard.

Comment: It didn't work. I don't want to try removing the BIOS battery. That doesn't guarantee success and I don't want to open up the laptop

Comment: @Melebius yes. The F2 selection is ignored even if it shows on screen highlighted

Comment: The only hope I have if I can do something from the command prompt of the windows setup disk (Shift+F10 after boot). Do you know how to disable or go to BIOS from cmd line at restart?

Answer (score 0):

Some computers will bypass an attempt at entering BIOS/UEFI after a restart, but will enter it just fine from a full power down. Some will only register the F2/F12 if pressed a *just* the right time.

Power the laptop down completely (hold the power button until all lights turn off and the fans stop spinning if necessary), then power it on again, then quickly and repeatedly press F2 until the Dell logo goes away. This should get you back into BIOS/UEFI and allow you to disable Secure Boot and/or UEFI boot mode (if necessary).